# How many codimension 1 submodules of $(\mathbb{Z}/2)^n$ are there?

Tags: linear-algebra, combinatorics

Let $\mathbb{Z}/2$ denote the ring of two elements. How many codimension-1 submodules of the $n$-dimensional free module $(\mathbb{Z}/2)^n$ are there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $\mathbb Z/2$ is a field, we're dealing with vector spaces here.  A codimension-1 vector subspace is given by the vanishing of some non-zero linear functional.  Over a general field, I'd have to add that linear functionals that differ by a nonzero scalar factor give the same hyperplane, but in $\mathbb Z/2$ the only nonzero scalar is $1$, so that issue doesn't arise.  Therefore, the number of codimension-1 subspaces is the number of non-zero elements of the dual space, i.e., $2^n-1$.  (In general, over a finite field of $q$ elements, an $n$-dimensional vector space has $(q^n-1)/(q-1)$ codimension-1 subspaces.)